# Can we get EntityMetadataWrapper to fill out unsaved autocomplete values?

Tags: 7, entities

I have a preview step in my entity form and I'm trying to show values about to be saved with EntityMetadataWrapper. I use the code below in my form builder function when in the preview step:

```
$entity = entity_get_controller($type)->create($form_state['values']);
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper($type, $entity);
```

I have a taxonomy term reference field that accepts multiple existing or new terms with an autocomplete/tagging widget. Existing terms can be iterated over with $wrapper->field_name but newly created terms will throw an EntityMetadataWrapperException.

Is there a way to force EntityMetadataWrapper to iterate correctly over newly created terms?